# SystemJS not substituting TS files with JS files?

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I recently started using SystemJS for my Angular 2 applications. However, it is causing me trouble since I can't make it substitute TS files with JS files.

Consider the following import for instance:

#### main.ts

```
import {SubscriptionsComponent} from './subscriptions.ts';
import {WelcomeComponent} from './welcome.ts';
```

#### main.js (the compiled result)

```
System.register(['./subscriptions.ts', './welcome.ts'], function(exports_1) {
    // ...
});
```

I would expect SystemJS to then request `subscriptions.js`, but instead, `subscriptions.ts` is requested, resulting in a 404.

I don't want to use a transpiler - I just want SystemJS to somehow understand that I need to request JS files instead.

Here's my config that I thought would help (however, this only works if including things like `foo.ts`, but not `./foo.ts`).

```
System.config({
        "baseURL": '/',
        "defaultJSExtensions": false,
        "paths": {
            "*.ts": "*.js"
        }
    });

System.import('components/main.ts');
```

The funny thing is that it doesn't request `components/main.ts`, it actually requests `components/main.js` as it should. It just doesn't work if `main.ts` includes additional files.

Comment: Is the app wide, or in specific sub-folders? Could you not just request it to use JS only files, using defaultExtension: js? A quick example of what I am refering to as i did with ng2-boostrap: https://gist.github.com/Wobbley/9dc33422e6ea1cf7d96e

Comment: Whats in your `tsconfig.json`? also your system config differs from the angular 2 recommended one: https://github.com/agconti/angualr2-heros/blob/master/index.html#L14

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, I'm not using SystemJS, but on the whole the documentation for modules in TypeScript suggests you don't use the file extension:

```
import {SubscriptionsComponent} from './subscriptions';
import {WelcomeComponent} from './welcome';
```

The following example works in Visual Studio Code editor, so perhaps you are having a problem with Atom in particular:

*mod.ts*

```
export class Example {
    doIt() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

*app.ts*

```
import {Example} from './mod'

var x = new Example();
```

Comment: Please see my comment on @ipinak's answer.

Comment: Also, this won't work with TypeScript. Atom doesn't seem to detect my import in that case.

Comment: I have performed a test compiling to `system` module kind in VS Code and it works without file extensions - perhaps there is a bug with Atom?

Comment: But how can this coexist with Angular 2's way of importing TypeScript declarations? For instance, `import {Component} from 'angular2/core'` in TypeScript doesn't actually refer to a `core.js` file - it refers to a declared module.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use transpiler add in your config `transpiler: none`.

Change `"defaultJSExtensions": true` and omit the extensions from your imports.

Do you still see the error?

Comment: This does indeed include JS files instead (and I already tried this) - however, my code is also riddled with existing imports from third party TypeScript such as Angular 2. For instance `angular2/core`, which is not a `.js` file, it is an explicit module.